# how to use liveData coroutine block

Tags: android-livedata

how to use liveData coroutine block

in offical doc

https://developer.android.google.cn/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#livedata

now can use livedata with coroutine in liveData block

```
val user: LiveData<User> = liveData {
    val data = database.loadUser() // loadUser is a suspend function.
    emit(data)
}
```

when i try to use like this

```
fun onLogin(v: View) {
    liveData(context = Dispatchers.IO) {
        val reqLogin = ReqLogin(account = account.value?:"", password = MD5(password.value?:""))
        val data = HttpManager.service(MobileApi::class.java).loginSuspend(reqLogin)
        emit(data.data!!)
    }
}
```

codes in block not executed

search and found that `liveData` block always use for assignment

https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/viewmodels-and-livedata-patterns-antipatterns-21efaef74a54

if want to refresh the livedata value, can use Transformations like

```
LiveData<Repo> repo = Transformations.switchMap(repoIdLiveData, repoId -> {
    if (repoId.isEmpty()) {
        return AbsentLiveData.create();
    }
    return repository.loadRepo(repoId);
});
```

but how can i use it when
1. activity onResume and refresh the data from server
2. some click event trigger the request and get some new data to show

in my login scenes, use viewModelScope seems more useful

```
fun onLogin(v: View) {
    val reqLogin = ReqLogin(account = account.value ?: "", password = MD5(password.value ?: ""))
    viewModelScope.launch {
        val data = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            HttpManager.service(MobileApi::class.java).loginSuspend(reqLogin)
        }
        _userInfo.value = data.data!!
        _isLogin.value = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    fun onLogin(v: View) {
    liveData(context = Dispatchers.IO) {
        val reqLogin = ReqLogin(account = account.value?:"", password = MD5(password.value?:""))
        val data = HttpManager.service(MobileApi::class.java).loginSuspend(reqLogin)
        emit(data.data!!)
    }
}
```

Code block is not executed because the documentation says that

> The code block starts executing when LiveData becomes active and is
>   automatically canceled after a configurable timeout when the LiveData
>   becomes inactive.

You should make it active by observing it.